# compare two columns and color greater in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I came across conditional formatting https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html 
But not sure how to implement it.
I have my result saved in dataframe, i am trying to do this color formatting based on if column2> column1:
color column2
else: do nothing 
and save the excel file.
any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for row in table:
    ws.write_row(i, 0, row)

    i += 1
    print("for i:", i)
    cell_pointer1 = "C${}".format(i) 
    cell_pointer2 = "D${}".format(i) 
    cell_pointer3 = "E${}".format(i) 
    print("cell pointer2:", format(cell_pointer2))

    ws.conditional_format(format(cell_pointer2) ,
        {'type':     'cell',
         'criteria': '>=',
         'value' : format(cell_pointer1),
         'format':   format2,
        })


    ws.conditional_format(format(cell_pointer2) ,
        {'type':     'cell',
         'criteria': '<',
         'value' : format(cell_pointer1),
         'format':   format1
        })

    ws.conditional_format(format(cell_pointer3) ,
       {'type':     'cell',
        'criteria': '>=',
        'value' : format(cell_pointer1),
        'format':   format2,
       })


    ws.conditional_format(format(cell_pointer3) ,
       {'type':     'cell',
        'criteria': '<',
        'value' : format(cell_pointer1),
        'format':   format1
       })
```

ws.set_column(0, 0, 25)

wb.close()

Answer (score 0):

```
   worksheet.conditional_format('B1:B9' ,
                         {'type':'formula',
                          'criteria': '=AND($A1<$B1,$B1>0)',
                          'format':   format1})
```

Comment: In type area enter formula then the python interpreter will process for user defined formula in CRITERIA section. format1 is the format that we want to do. This is format col B from row 1 to 9  if col.B>col.A and Additional criteria is B1>0.